# remove and add margin based on amount scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css

Css

```
.menu {
   margin-top: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 25px;
   position: fixed;
}
```

I am trying to make it, when the user scrolls down 100px from the top of the document, the `margin-top` of element `.menu` is removed.

Comment: Put on your code Html  in jsfiddle

Comment: Put the 100px margin inside a class e.g. `.menu.margin`. Use javascript, eventlistener on scroll, when your document is >= 100px from top, remove the class `.margin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain JavaScript it may look like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  document.querySelector('.menu').style.marginTop =
    Math.max(0, 100 - this.scrollY) + 'px';
}, false);
```

```css
.menu {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px dotted;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu"></div>
```